# react-native-canvas fillRect is not being drawn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, canvas

I am trying to draw a simple rectangle in react-native using react-native-canvas, Here's my code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Canvas from 'react-native-canvas';

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const ctx = ref.current.getContext('2d');
      if (ctx) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
        Alert.alert('Canvas is ready');
      }
    }
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Canvas ref={ref} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'black' }} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

the program is entering the `if(ctx)` loop as `Alert.alert()` is being displayed, but fillRect and fillStyle are not working?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/canvas/overview/) implementation from the React Native Skia documentation worked for me.

I.e., wrap your if function with a setTimeout

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32959040)